# Why has a new chapter of ‘Nichijou’ been released when the serialization ended in 2015?

Tags: manga-production, nichijou

The gag comic manga, *Nichijou* ended in 2015, based on this [article](https://myanimelist.net/news/41798578), posted on *MyAnimelist* on Aug 24, 2015. Suddenly, in 2021, the serialization continued based on this [article](https://myanimelist.net/news/64704301). Does this kind of activity really happen often in the anime and manga industry? Because, this is the first time that I have seen this kind of events. I mean, the manga "officially" ended in 2015, and suddenly, it continued its serialization.

Is this possible for other manga, too, that have ended many years ago?

[image: Nichijou new serialization info.]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The title and the bulk of the question seem to be asking separate questions - the question in the title, why *Nichijou* is being re-serialized, is relatively easy to answer.

The official answer is: [because the author, Keiichi Arai, wants to.](https://twitter.com/himaraya/status/1450733528367484932?s=20) That is, as far as I know, all there is to it - he hasn't given any other reason in his Twitter or anywhere else.

As long as the author and company responsible for its serialization agree (and depending on the contract clause, one of them might not even be necessary), there isn't legally really anything preventing re-serialization of a completed manga.

Of course, the bigger hurdle might be elsewhere - a completed manga ideally means that its story is essentially complete, and there isn't anything significant that can be added postscript without it feeling extraneous. So often, neither the fans nor the mangaka really desire additional content within the same manga series. This doesn't preclude the telling of additional stories within the same universe, of course, but those stories are often different enough (e.g. a change in main character or tone, a time skip, etc.) to warrant a sequel or spin-off (e.g. the [*Kosaku Shima*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaku_Shima) series, *Naruto* -> *Boruto*, *To Love Ru* -> *To Love Ru Darkness*)

As it stands, there are a few reasons why a completed (and not simply discontinued or abandoned) manga would re-serialize much later without moving to a sequel or spin-off:

1. The manga has a more omnibus tone, and the lack of a overarching story means additional chapters are less likely to feel tacked on (*Nichijou*, as posed in the question, would be a prime example)
2. The manga ends with conclusion of an arc (and less of a grand finale), and the mangaka had some ideas to continue the story - and decides to go for it after a hiatus. ([*Rurouni Kenshin* Hokkaido arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rurouni_Kenshin:_The_Hokkaido_Arc) is a borderline example, and [*Dragon Quest: The Adventure of Dai* Underworld arc](https://dragonquest.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Quest:_The_Adventure_of_Dai) would be a planned, but unexecuted, case.)
3. The ending was unsatisfactory, and a proper conclusion is added later  ([*Shaman King*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Shaman_King_chapters#Chapters_collected_exclusively_in_kanzenban_format))
4. There are new ideas, but not enough (or require too much continuity) to justify a reboot, spin-off or sequel ([likely *Bleach*](https://www.cbr.com/bleach-new-arc-facts-details/))

There will be other reasons and examples of course, but the above is the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: Shaman king first ended right before the main character went to confront the final villain. I remember the final page of shaman king had a note from the author saying "I will take a break from shaman king to go work on a new manga. I promise to come back and finish the story at some point in the future." I sat there stunned, bewildered, that the author abandoned their work so close to the end to go start a new project. Thankfully, they did come back and finish it years later.

Comment: Another example that takes your option 2 and extends it: _Saki: Achiga-hen (episode of side-A)_ is itself a spinoff, which finished while the main manga _(Saki)_ went on. It covered a somewhat self-contained side story that was a complete story arc by itself and led up to future events that would be seen in the main manga. Years later, the spinoff suddenly resumed and went on to cover those same events from the side story’s protagonists’ perspective. (Both manga are currently ongoing.)

Comment: Plus, of course, someone might decide it was a cash cow and go on even when it makes no aesthetic sense.